# Importing data from one Neo4j server to another server (Copy Entire Subgraph)

Tags: import, neo4j

I want to copy entire subgraph from one server to another server via a cypher in Neo 4j .
I have a Neo 4j on Host 1 and another Neo 4j on Host 2 .
My requirement to copy the graph from Host 1 and insert into Host 2

Comment: You can clone (copy) the entire neo4j_home directory and put it on another host.

Comment: I want to this via cypher . We are in process to create a job which will transit the data from one server to another server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [apoc.bolt.execute](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.bolt/apoc.bolt.execute/) procedure to move data from one graph to another graph :

Here is an example moving data from the standard movies graph to another graph called `movies888` :

Replace `username`, `password` and `host` with your values

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m)
WITH n, r, m
CALL apoc.bolt.execute(
    'bolt://<username>:<password>@<host>:7687',
    '
        MERGE (p:Person {name: $n.name}) SET p = $n
        MERGE (m:Movie {title: $m.title}) SET m = $m
        MERGE (p)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m)
        SET r = $r
    ',
    {n: n{.*}, m: m{.*}, r: r{.*}}, {databaseName: 'movies888'}
)
YIELD row RETURN count(*)
```